# Get list of users projects in Google Cloud Platform using OAuth2 nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

In order to access GCP as an end user I am successfully exchanging a code for credentials including an access token and refresh token using the nodejs oauth2 library from google.

I can then use these credentials to access Google BigQuery using a projectId, however I would like to get a list of projects for the end user so that they can select the project.

I don't seem to be able to find an endpoint that will provide this.  I have tried https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-resource-manager, however this requires the end user to enable the Resource Manager API, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

[projects.list](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/list) is provided by Cloud Resource Manager API. If you want the functionality, you've no alternative but to use that API.

All Google's API calls are scoped to a project. You should only need to enable the API in the project that's authenticating your users, i.e. the one containing the OAuth client.